# MySQL LEFT JOIN is slow and taking 27.82sec

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Here is my MySQL query which is taking 27secs time for execution.

```
SELECT company_info.industry
     , company_info.name
     , company_aliases.name 
FROM searcher_db.company_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN searcher_db.company_aliases ON company_info.id = company_aliases.id;
```

company_aliases has 1883 records ,company_info has 71179 records and indexes are shown on the images.

[image]
[image]

Please anyone help me on this ? Why is it taking so much of time and how to improve the query ?

Comment: Please paste the Explain Plan of the query

Comment: There is no WHERE clause. Do you really want to read all Records? Please check WHERE clause and post EXPLAIN PLAN like Sashi Kant says.

Comment: Yes i need all the results. I have to store all these 70000+ results  into a cache and using it for for search purpose.

Comment: Really, your query return 71179 records (all from company_info). Really need LEFT OUTER JOIN. Please explain your expected query result. (ok, my question is anserwed in between)

Comment: But why cache data for later searches? You've a dbms, the perfect tool for searching data, can't you use it? (BTW. if this data load is done only once, does 27 seconds really matter?)

Comment: @jarlh you are correct. Its actually one time happening. I am not querying it multiple times , this query run while starting the server. i think its ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Index on company_info.id and company_aliases.id, alias

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

Then, instead of setting PRIMARY KEY (`name`), set it on table.id. In background MySQL convert text to ASCII and then process it and therefore takes time, so avoid doing that. Searching and other operation are faster on Number, instead of string. See if that help.

Comment: You say "SQL convert text to ASCII", but I assume you mean MySQL?